# Junit for Spring Integration Components

Tags: junit, spring-integration, spring-test

I have following configuration setup for calling a REST service.

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
    SubscribableChannel requestChannel= new DirectChannel();
    return requestChannel;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel responseChannel() {
    SubscribableChannel responseChannel = new DirectChannel();
    return responseChannel;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel")
public MessageHandler httResponseMessageHandler(MessageChannel responseChannel,
        HeaderMapper<HttpHeaders> headerMapper, RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice) {
    List<Advice> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(retryAdvice);
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("https://localhost:8080/myrest/service/");
    handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
    handler.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper);
    handler.setOutputChannel(responseChannel);
    handler.setExpectedResponseType(RtpResponse.class);
    handler.setAdviceChain(list);
    return handler;
}
```

Below is the configuration of gateway and service activator to send request and fetch response.

```
@Override
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="responseChannel")
public void receiveResponse(Message<RtpResponse> message) {
    LOGGER.info("Message: " + message);
    LOGGER.info("Message: " + message.getPayload());
    LOGGER.info(message.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}

@Override
@Gateway(requestChannel = "requestChannel")
public void sendRequest(RtpRequestBody requestBody) {
    requestChannel
    .send(
            MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestBody)
            .setHeader("Accept","application/json")
            .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json")
            .setHeader(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL,errorChannel)
            .build()
        );
}
```

I am stuck on how to write Junit for this flow. I am not sure if I need to restructure this flow into IntegrationFlow that would help with writing Junit tests for this. Advise needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from Artem's answer

```
@Autowired
private SubscribableChannel employeeGetMethodResponseChannel;

@Autowired
private EmployeeSearchService employeeSearchService;

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplateMock;

private EmployeeDetail employeeDetailInResponse;

private Employee employeeInRequest;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    employeeInRequest = new Employee();
    employeeInRequest.setEmployeeId(1L);

    employeeDetailInResponse = new EmployeeDetail();
    employeeDetailInResponse.setEmployeeId(1L);
}

@Test
public void testGetRequest() {
    Mockito.when(restTemplateMock.postForObject("https://localhost:8080/myrest/service/", EmployeeDetail.class))
            .thenReturn(employeeDetailInResponse);
    this.employeeSearchService.employeeSearch(employeeInRequest);
}

@Test
public void testResponse() {
    this.responseChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            Assert.assertTrue("Test failed", ((EmployeeDetail) message.getPayload()).getEmployeeId().equals(1L));

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what problem you have, but you need just to get a gateway bean for that `sendRequest()` and call it:

```
@Autowired
MyGateway myGateway;

@Test
void myTest() {
    this.myGateway.sendRequest(...);
}
```

Not sure though why don't you expect a return from that gateway method, but that is your logic anyway. To handle a reply in the `responseChannel`, you can consider to use Spring Integration Testing Framework with its `MockIntegration.mockMessageHandler()` and `MockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor()` to replace that your `receiveResponse()` Service Activator with something what you can verify and assert in the test-case.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/testing.html#test-context

**UPDATE**

> Unfortunately, we cannot upgrade to version 5.0.5. Could you please guide me to spring integration testing documentation for version 4.3.9

No, there is no such one. That is really a new functionality in Spring Integration 5.0: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/whats-new.html.

You can though get `requestChannel` bean and call its `addInterceptor(ChannelInterceptor interceptor)` before performing test-case. In the `ChannelInterceptor.perSend()` you can get a reply message and verify it.

Comment: Hello Artem, Unfortunately, we cannot upgrade to version 5.0.5. Could you please guide me to spring integration testing documentation for version 4.3.9 

Thanks